# Testing code for An+B microsyntax parsing library

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a small package that provides some API for playing around with [the <An+B> CSS microsyntax](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#anb-microsyntax). It is 100% type hinted and tested, but doesn't actually have any real/useful features and this question is not about the main code anyway.

I was introduced to [the Hypothesis testing library](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in [a previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288612) and have taken a liking to it, so this package is a way for me to practice using it. Therefore, I'm asking for a review of my testing code. Only test files are presented here; other files can be found at [the package's repository](https://github.com/InSyncWithFoo/a-n-plus-b).

Here's the project structure (irrelevant files removed):

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── src
│   └── a_n_plus_b
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── _grammar.py
│       └── py.typed
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_alternate_constructors.py
│   ├── test_indices.py
│   └── test_other_methods.py
└── tox.ini
```

#### `tests/__init__.py`

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterable
from typing import Any, ParamSpec, TypeVar

from _pytest.mark import ParameterSet
from hypothesis import example
from hypothesis.strategies import composite, DrawFn, integers, SearchStrategy

from a_n_plus_b import ANPlusB


_T = TypeVar('_T')
_P = ParamSpec('_P')

_Decorator = Callable[[Callable[_P, _T]], Callable[_P, _T]]

newlines = ['\r\n', '\r', '\n', '\f']
whitespace = ['\t', '\x20'] + newlines
blank = [''] + whitespace


def join(whatever: Iterable[Any]) -> str:
    return ''.join(map(str, whatever))


# Originally from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312417
def examples(
    parameter_sets: Iterable[ParameterSet | tuple[Any, ...] | Any]
) -> _Decorator[_P, _T]:
    parameter_sets = list(parameter_sets)
    
    def inner(test_case: Callable[_P, _T]) -> Callable[_P, _T]:
        for parameter_set in reversed(parameter_sets):
            if isinstance(parameter_set, ParameterSet):
                parameter_set = parameter_set.values
            
            if not isinstance(parameter_set, tuple):
                parameter_set = tuple([parameter_set])
            
            test_case = example(*parameter_set)(test_case)
        
        return test_case
    
    return inner


@composite
def a_n_plus_b_instances(
    draw: DrawFn,
    steps: SearchStrategy[int] = integers(),
    offsets: SearchStrategy[int] = integers()
) -> SearchStrategy[ANPlusB]:
    return ANPlusB(draw(steps), draw(offsets))
```

#### `tests/test_alternate_constructors.py`

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, TypeVar

import pytest
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import (
    composite, DrawFn, floats, integers, just, lists,
    one_of, sampled_from, SearchStrategy, tuples
)

from a_n_plus_b import (
    ANPlusB, ComplexWithNonIntegerPart,
    EmptyInput, InputIsNotParsable
)
from . import examples, join, whitespace


_E = TypeVar('_E')
_T = TypeVar('_T')


def _make_complex(example: tuple[int | float, int | float]) -> complex:
    return complex(*example)


def _starts_with_sign(example: tuple[str, Any]) -> bool:
    text, _ = example
    
    return text[0] in ('+', '-')


def _casing_scrambled(text: str) -> SearchStrategy[str]:
    lowercase = text.lower()
    uppercase = text.upper()
    
    substrategies = (sampled_from(chars) for chars in zip(lowercase, uppercase))
    
    return tuples(*substrategies).map(''.join)


@composite
def _variations(draw: DrawFn, text: str) -> str:
    scrambled_text = draw(_casing_scrambled(text))
    
    return draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(scrambled_text))


def _tupled_with(value: _T) -> Callable[[_E], tuple[_E, _T]]:
    def tupled_with_given_value(example: _E) -> tuple[_E, _T]:
        return example, value
    
    return tupled_with_given_value


def _whitespace_sequences() -> SearchStrategy[str]:
    return lists(
        sampled_from(whitespace),
        min_size = 1, max_size = 10
    ).map(''.join)


def whitespace_sequences_or_empty() -> SearchStrategy[str]:
    return _whitespace_sequences() | just('')


def with_surrounding_whitespace(text: str) -> SearchStrategy[str]:
    return tuples(
        whitespace_sequences_or_empty(),
        just(text),
        whitespace_sequences_or_empty()
    ) \
        .map(join)


def _non_integral_floats() -> SearchStrategy[float]:
    return floats().filter(lambda example: not example.is_integer())


def _operators() -> SearchStrategy[str]:
    return sampled_from(['+', '-'])


def _signs() -> SearchStrategy[str]:
    return just('') | _operators()


def _digits() -> SearchStrategy[int]:
    return integers(min_value = 0, max_value = 9)


@composite
def _integers_with_potentially_superfluous_sign(draw: DrawFn) -> str:
    sign = draw(_signs())
    digits = draw(lists(_digits(), min_size = 1, max_size = 10).map(join))
    
    return draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(sign + digits))


@composite
def _a_values(draw: DrawFn) -> str:
    sign = draw(_signs())
    digits = draw(lists(_digits(), max_size = 10).map(join))
    
    return sign + digits


def _b_values() -> SearchStrategy[str]:
    return lists(_digits(), min_size = 1, max_size = 10).map(join)


class ParseANPlusBTestCases:
    
    @staticmethod
    @composite
    def valid(draw: DrawFn) -> tuple[str, tuple[int, int]]:
        a = draw(_a_values())
        n = draw(sampled_from(['n', 'N']))
        operator = draw(_signs())
        
        if not a:
            step = 0
        elif a == '+':
            step = 1
        elif a == '-':
            step = -1
        else:
            step = int(a)
        
        if operator:
            b = draw(_b_values())
            offset = int(f'{operator}{b}')
        else:
            b = ''
            offset = 0
        
        operator = draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(operator))
        text = draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(f'{a}{n}{operator}{b}'))
        
        return text, (step, offset)
    
    @staticmethod
    @composite
    def whitespace_after_a_sign(draw: DrawFn) -> str:
        valid_cases = ParseANPlusBTestCases.valid().filter(_starts_with_sign)
        valid_input = draw(valid_cases)[0]
        
        a_sign, rest = valid_input[0], valid_input[1:]
        invalid_whitespace = draw(_whitespace_sequences())
        
        return f'{a_sign}{invalid_whitespace}{rest}'
    
    @staticmethod
    @composite
    def missing_b(draw: DrawFn) -> str:
        a = draw(_a_values())
        n = draw(sampled_from(['n', 'N']))
        operator = draw(_operators())
        
        operator = draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(operator))
        
        return draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(f'{a}{n}{operator}'))
    
    @staticmethod
    @composite
    def missing_operator(draw: DrawFn) -> str:
        a = draw(_a_values())
        n = draw(sampled_from(['n', 'N']))
        b = draw(_b_values())
        
        b = draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(b))
        
        return draw(with_surrounding_whitespace(f'{a}{n}{b}'))


@given(
    one_of([
        _variations('odd').map(_tupled_with((2, 1))),
        _variations('even').map(_tupled_with((2, 0)))
    ])
)
def test_parse_odd_even(text_and_expected):
    text, expected = text_and_expected
    instance = ANPlusB.parse(text)
    
    assert (instance.step, instance.offset) == expected


@given(_integers_with_potentially_superfluous_sign())
def test_parse_integer(text):
    expected = int(text)
    
    instance = ANPlusB.parse(text)
    
    assert instance.step == 0
    assert instance.offset == expected


@given(whitespace_sequences_or_empty())
def test_parse_empty(text):
    with pytest.raises(EmptyInput):
        ANPlusB.parse(text)


@given(ParseANPlusBTestCases.valid())
@examples([
    (['+3n+2', (3, 2)]),
    (['+4n+0', (4, 0)]),
    (['+6n', (6, 0)]),
    (['+5n-0', (5, 0)]),
    (['+7n-1', (7, -1)]),
    
    (['3n+2', (3, 2)]),
    (['4n+0', (4, 0)]),
    (['6n', (6, 0)]),
    (['5n-0', (5, 0)]),
    (['7n-1', (7, -1)]),
    
    (['+0n+2', (0, 2)]),
    (['+0n+0', (0, 0)]),
    (['+0n', (0, 0)]),
    (['+0n-0', (0, 0)]),
    (['+0n-1', (0, -1)]),
    
    (['0n+2', (0, 2)]),
    (['0n+0', (0, 0)]),
    (['0n', (0, 0)]),
    (['0n-0', (0, 0)]),
    (['0n-1', (0, -1)]),
    
    (['-0n+2', (0, 2)]),
    (['-0n+0', (0, 0)]),
    (['-0n', (0, 0)]),
    (['-0n-0', (0, 0)]),
    (['-0n-1', (0, -1)]),
    
    (['-3n+2', (-3, 2)]),
    (['-4n+0', (-4, 0)]),
    (['-6n', (-6, 0)]),
    (['-5n-0', (-5, 0)]),
    (['-7n-1', (-7, -1)]),
])
def test_parse_a_n_plus_b(text_and_expected):
    text, expected = text_and_expected
    instance = ANPlusB.parse(text)
    
    assert (instance.step, instance.offset) == expected


@given(
    one_of([
        ParseANPlusBTestCases.whitespace_after_a_sign(),
        ParseANPlusBTestCases.missing_b(),
        ParseANPlusBTestCases.missing_operator()
    ])
)
def test_parse_invalid(text):
    with pytest.raises(InputIsNotParsable):
        ANPlusB.parse(text)


@given(
    one_of([
        tuples(integers(), integers()).map(_make_complex),
        integers(),
        integers().map(float)
    ])
)
def test_from_complex(value):
    instance = ANPlusB.from_complex(value)
    expected = (int(value.imag), int(value.real))
    
    assert (instance.step, instance.offset) == expected


@given(
    one_of([
        tuples(_non_integral_floats(), integers()),
        tuples(integers(), _non_integral_floats()),
        tuples(_non_integral_floats(), _non_integral_floats())
    ]) \
        .map(_make_complex)
)
def test_from_complex_invalid(value):
    with pytest.raises(ComplexWithNonIntegerPart):
        ANPlusB.from_complex(value)
```

#### `tests/test_indices.py`

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from itertools import product
from typing import cast, Literal

import pytest
from _pytest.mark import ParameterSet
from hypothesis import assume, given
from hypothesis.strategies import (
    booleans, composite, DrawFn, from_type, integers, just,
    one_of, sampled_from, SearchStrategy, tuples
)

from a_n_plus_b import ANPlusB, InvalidNumberOfChildren, InvalidOrder
from . import a_n_plus_b_instances, examples


_Order = Literal['ascending', 'descending', 'default']
_TestCase = tuple[ANPlusB, tuple[int, bool, _Order], Iterable[int]]


def _ascending(values: Iterable[int]) -> Iterable[int]:
    return sorted(values)


def _descending(indices: Iterable[int]) -> Iterable[int]:
    return sorted(indices, reverse = True)


def _from_last(indices: Iterable[int], population: int) -> Iterable[int]:
    return [population - index + 1 for index in indices]


def _sign(value: int, /) -> Literal['negative', 'positive', 'zero']:
    return 'negative' if value < 0 else 'positive' if value > 0 else 'zero'


def _describe(test_case: _TestCase) -> str:
    instance, (population, from_last, order), _ = test_case
    step, offset = instance.step, instance.offset
    
    descriptions = [
        f'{_sign(step)} step',
        f'{_sign(offset)} offset',
        f'from last' if from_last else 'from first',
        f'{order}'
    ]
    
    return ', '.join(descriptions)


def _human_integers(
    min_value: int = -(2 ** 16),
    max_value: int = 2 ** 16,
) -> SearchStrategy[int]:
    return integers(
        min_value = max(-(2 ** 16), min_value),
        max_value = min(2 ** 16, max_value)
    )


def _orders() -> SearchStrategy[_Order]:
    return cast(
        SearchStrategy[_Order],
        sampled_from(['ascending', 'descending', 'default'])
    )


def _non_positive_step_and_offset_test_cases() -> SearchStrategy[_TestCase]:
    return tuples(
        a_n_plus_b_instances(
            integers(max_value = 0),
            integers(max_value = 0)
        ),
        tuples(integers(min_value = 0), booleans(), _orders()),
        just(list[int]())
    )


@composite
def _zero_step_test_cases(draw: DrawFn) -> _TestCase:
    argument_sets = tuples(integers(min_value = 0), booleans(), _orders())
    
    instance = draw(a_n_plus_b_instances(just(0), integers()))
    population, from_last, order = draw(argument_sets)
    
    b = instance.offset
    
    index = population - b + 1 if from_last else b
    expected = [index] if 1 <= b <= population else list[int]()
    
    return instance, (population, from_last, order), expected


@composite
def _non_positive_step_zero_offset_test_cases(draw: DrawFn) -> _TestCase:
    argument_sets = tuples(integers(min_value = 0), booleans(), _orders())
    
    instance = draw(a_n_plus_b_instances(integers(max_value = -1), just(0)))
    arguments = draw(argument_sets)
    
    return instance, arguments, list[int]()


def _test_case_group(
    instance: ANPlusB,
    population: int,
    base_case_expected: Iterable[int]
) -> list[ParameterSet]:
    test_cases = []
    from_last_and_order_matrix = product(
        [False, True],
        ['default', 'ascending', 'descending']
    )
    
    for from_last, order in from_last_and_order_matrix:
        expected = base_case_expected
        
        if from_last:
            expected = _from_last(base_case_expected, population)
        
        if order == 'ascending':
            expected = _ascending(expected)
        elif order == 'descending':
            expected = _descending(expected)
        
        test_case = (instance, (population, from_last, order), expected)
        test_cases.append(
            pytest.param(test_case, id = _describe(test_case))
        )
    
    return test_cases


@given(
    one_of([
        _non_positive_step_and_offset_test_cases(),
        _zero_step_test_cases(),
        _non_positive_step_zero_offset_test_cases()
    ])
)
@examples([
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(3, 0), 100, list(range(3, 101, 3))),
    
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(-2, 6), 10, [6, 4, 2]),
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(-1, 4), 8, [4, 3, 2, 1]),
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(-3, 8), 18, [8, 5, 2]),
    
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(4, -5), 20, [3, 7, 11, 15, 19]),
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(5, -2), 12, [3, 8]),
    
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(2, 1), 15, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]),
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(3, 1), 10, [1, 4, 7, 10]),
    *_test_case_group(ANPlusB(1, 4), 11, [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
])
def test_indices(instance_arguments_expected: _TestCase):
    instance, arguments, expected = instance_arguments_expected
    population, from_last, order = arguments
    
    indices = instance.indices(population, from_last = from_last, order = order)
    
    assert list(indices) == expected


@given(
    a_n_plus_b_instances(),
    integers(), booleans(), from_type(str)
)
def test_indices_invalid_order(instance, population, from_last, order):
    assume(order not in ('ascending', 'descending', 'default'))
    
    with pytest.raises(InvalidOrder):
        instance.indices(population, from_last = from_last, order = order)


@given(
    a_n_plus_b_instances(),
    integers(max_value = -1), booleans(), _orders()
)
def test_indices_invalid_number_of_children(
    instance, population, from_last, order
):
    with pytest.raises(InvalidNumberOfChildren):
        instance.indices(population, from_last = from_last, order = order)
```

#### `tests/test_other_methods.py`

```py
import pytest
from hypothesis import given, infer
from hypothesis.strategies import from_type, integers

from a_n_plus_b import ANPlusB, IncorrectUseOfConstructor
from . import a_n_plus_b_instances


_EqTestCase = tuple[ANPlusB, '_ANPlusBSubclass', bool]


class _ANPlusBSubclass(ANPlusB):
    pass


@given(integers(), integers())
def test_construction(step, offset):
    instance = ANPlusB(step, offset)
    
    assert instance.step == step
    assert instance.offset == offset


@given(integers())
def test_construction_single_argument(offset):
    instance = ANPlusB(offset)
    
    assert instance.step == 0
    assert instance.offset == offset


@given(infer)
def test_construction_invalid(text: str):
    with pytest.raises(IncorrectUseOfConstructor):
        ANPlusB(text)  # noqa


@pytest.mark.parametrize(('instance', 'expected'), [
    (ANPlusB(0, -2), '-2'),
    (ANPlusB(0, 0), '0'),
    (ANPlusB(0, 2), '2'),
    
    (ANPlusB(1, -3), 'n-3'),
    (ANPlusB(1, 0), 'n'),
    (ANPlusB(1, 3), 'n+3'),
    
    (ANPlusB(-1, -4), '-n-4'),
    (ANPlusB(-1, 0), '-n'),
    (ANPlusB(-1, 4), '-n+4'),
    
    (ANPlusB(3, 4), '3n+4'),
    (ANPlusB(3, 0), '3n'),
    (ANPlusB(3, -5), '3n-5'),
    
    (ANPlusB(-4, 5), '-4n+5'),
    (ANPlusB(-4, 0), '-4n'),
    (ANPlusB(-4, -6), '-4n-6')
])
def test_str(instance, expected):
    assert str(instance) == expected
    assert repr(instance) == f'{ANPlusB.__name__}({expected})'


@given(a_n_plus_b_instances())
def test_values(instance):
    a, b = instance.step, instance.offset
    
    for index, value in zip(range(10), instance.values()):
        assert value == a * index + b


@given(a_n_plus_b_instances(), integers(min_value = 0))
def test_values_contain_getitem(instance, index):
    a, b = instance.step, instance.offset
    value = instance.values()[index]
    
    assert value == a * index + b
    assert value in instance.values()


@given(
    a_n_plus_b_instances(),
    from_type(object).filter(lambda o: not isinstance(o, int))
)
def test_values_not_contain(instance, item):
    assert item not in instance.values()


@given(a_n_plus_b_instances(), integers(max_value = -1))
def test_getitem_invalid(instance, index):
    with pytest.raises(IndexError):
        _ = instance.values()[index]


@given(a_n_plus_b_instances())
def test_eq(this):
    a, b = this.step, this.offset
    that = ANPlusB(a, b)
    
    assert this == that
    assert hash(this) == hash(that) == hash((a, b))


@pytest.mark.parametrize(('this', 'that', 'expected'), [
    (ANPlusB(-2, -3), ANPlusB(-2, -3), True),
    (ANPlusB(-1, 0), ANPlusB(-1, 0), True),
    (ANPlusB(0, -5), ANPlusB(0, -5), True),
    (_ANPlusBSubclass(-4, -3), _ANPlusBSubclass(-4, -3), True),
    (_ANPlusBSubclass(-1, -2), _ANPlusBSubclass(-1, -2), True),
    (_ANPlusBSubclass(0, 0), _ANPlusBSubclass(0, 0), True),
    (ANPlusB(0, 0), _ANPlusBSubclass(0, 0), True),
    (_ANPlusBSubclass(0, 0), ANPlusB(0, 0), True),
    (ANPlusB(3, 4), ANPlusB(4, 3), False),
    (_ANPlusBSubclass(3, 4), _ANPlusBSubclass(4, 3), False),
    (ANPlusB(-2, -3), ANPlusB(-4, -5), False),
    (_ANPlusBSubclass(-1, -2), _ANPlusBSubclass(-3, -4), False),
])
def test_eq_subclass(this, that, expected):
    assert (this == that) is expected
```

Answer (score 2):

Kudos for embarking on this adventure!
Stochastic testing can certainly reveal surprising
things about the target code.

## VT

No idea what your requirements are.
But apparently they mention form-feed and horizontal-tab,
and are well aligned with `isspace()`.
That is, `string.whitespace` seems relevant.

```
newlines = ['\r\n', '\r', '\n', '\f']
whitespace = ['\t', '\x20'] + newlines
```

Vertical-tab `\v` is missing.
Just sayin'.

And thank goodness the requirements are
simple enough that we needn't worry about
decimal 160 NBSP and its ilk, such as ZWSP.
(Which answers the question: When is a space not a space?)

## numeric tower

```
def _make_complex(example: tuple[int | float, int | float]) -> complex:
    return complex(*example)
```

Well, we needn't make the signature quite so complex.

The [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower)
explains that

> when an argument is annotated as having type float, an argument of type int is acceptable

That is, `int` is subsumed by `float`,
despite the lack of an inheritance relationship
for these primitives,
and the fact that python `int`s can certainly
represent quantities of far greater magnitude
than an IEEE double can.

This gives us the more readable:

```
def _make_complex(example: tuple[float, float]) -> complex:
    ...
```

## edge cases

I like `_casing_scrambled`.
Given a long string, it can certainly generate a great many possibilities.
It would take an exponentially long time to generate all of them.

I wonder if there is value in offering a variant
which simply downcases the "middle" bulk of the input string,
then picks a random index and length to upcase.
The idea would be to more rapidly explore the space
in order to provoke target code bugs.
I am thinking of the several implementations I've encountered
for converting between snake_case & camelCase,
and the subtle bugs they exhibit near non-alphabetics
like `_` underscore or digits.

## magic number

```
def _whitespace_sequences() -> ... :
    return ...
        min_size = 1, max_size = 10 ...
```

Consider promoting `10` up into a keyword default signature parameter.

Or make it a global?
I see at least three subsequent uses of it, e.g. in `_b_values`.
Maybe we want to admit of 33-bit numbers greater than four billion?

## lines of code

I agree with each function individually, they're doing the right thing.

Overall, it seems like a lot of verbiage, though.

For example, when I look at the `test_parse_a_n_plus_b` `@examples` I
like and agree with them.
But I can't help but think a regex would have solved 90%
of extracting `expected` from each input string.

The subsequent `@given` `@one_of`'s
really do validate the power of the technique,
concisely describing edge cases to be handled.

## positional only

```
def _sign(value: int, /) -> ...
```

Maybe delete the `/` slash?
It's not obvious to me why it's needed.

---

This is an impressive effort.

Maybe it was worth it?
Or maybe it ran into diminishing returns,
compared to the effort of how a less exhaustive approach
would still manage to exercise an interesting fraction
of the target code's state space.

I would love to see you write up "mistakes uncovered", that is,
what the test code taught you about evolving target code.
And if the testing approach suggested API changes
that improve accessibility / testability of more
of the state space.

Comment: I second your final paragraph - it would be very valuable (and perhaps motivational) to learn how this approach was helpful to the asker.

Comment: Regarding the whitespace requirements, I didn't make that up. It's defined by [the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#whitespace-diagram).

Comment: @InSync, excellent, thank you for the URL citation. Feel free to add a one-line citation to the source code, so future maintainers will know what it's intending to implement.